# Django Inline Formset Inside Model Formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i have two models named product and productimage .I will have multiple

images for product. So in this application, i want to create multiple

products and each products i want to create multiple images in a single

form using modelformset_factory and inlineformset_factory. i tried, but

it was not success. how can i do that.

here product is a modelformset and productimage is an inlineformset

```
models.py :


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
Product_modelformset = modelformset_factory(Product, form=ProductForm, extra=0, min_num=1)

Productimage_inlineformset = inlineformset_factory(Product, ProductImage, form=ProductImageForm, extra=0,
                                                    min_num=1, max_num=5, can_delete=True)
```

views.py

```
def create_product(request):
    template = "frontend/create_product.html"
context = {}

product_formset = Product_modelformset(queryset=Product.objects.none(), prefix="product_formset")

productimage_formset = Productimage_inlineformset(prefix="productimage_formset")

if request.method == 'POST':
    pass
........
.........

context["product_formset"] = product_formset
context["productimage_formset"] = productimage_formset

return render(request, template, context)
```

create_product.html

```
{% for form in product_formset.forms %}
        <div class="form_items">
            <p class="lead">Product ITems</p>
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
        {% for form in productimage_formset.forms %}
        <div class="image_items">
            <p class="lead">image items</p>
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div.form_items').formset({
                prefix: "{{ product_formset.prefix }}"
            });
            $('div.image_items').formset({
                prefix: "{{ productimage_formset.prefix }}"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You can do from my last explanation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119792/django-model-formset-factory-and-forms/40125395#40125395

Comment: @marin thanks for your comment. actually i want to put a formset inside another formset. i want to create  multiple product and in each product i want to create multiple images